# erratic audio levels on windows vista

Tags: windows-vista, audio, headphones

I'm somewhat hard of hearing. I've been listening to my windows Vista machine with a pair of headphones so I don't annoy the others.

I have 2 issues:

1) the volume varies enormously depending on the source. Having a windows alert occur while I am listening to a DVD or Youtube is a painful experience. Is there a preferred way to set all the different audio controls so I have a more constant volume? I already have lowered the volumes of the windows alerts.

2)Is there a way to limit the volume of my headphones to protect what is left of my hearing? Is there a software solution or should I be going for a hardware limiter?

thanks
retired dude

Answer (score 1):

different audio cards usually have a 'mixer' program that comes with them, or sometimes you can mix volumes in windows itself. I'm on 7, so I don't recall exactly for Vista, but clicking once (left click) on the little volume icon down by the clock, in the taskbar, brings up volume slider with 'mixer' underneath.

Depending on how many apps I have open, the next window changes... I can have Windows Media Player set at 50%, with WoW at 90%, etc etc.

Try opening a few different apps, and check there to see if that works?